# Are there any Ajax-based UML modeling tools?

Tags: uml, modeling

I'm looking for something like [WWW SQL Designer](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=default) for UML Modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.umlcanvas.org/ (no longer online)

edit: https://github.com/christophevg/UmlCanvas

---

Comment: Seems like this was downvoted because the URL is no longer online.
The project is available on github: https://github.com/christophevg/UmlCanvas

Answer (score 2):

This one is not in Ajax, it's in flash, at least it is online: http://www.gskinner.com/gmodeler/launch.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

Sequence diagrams are UML too.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally UML but it's super user-friendly and automatically generates an AJAX application prototype based on your model. it saves us a lot of time. http://www.xifactory.com